# How to get the alpha value of a Drawable for api less than 19

Tags: android, android-drawable, alpha, android-api-levels

I have a drawable object in my Activity. `setAlpha()` for drawable was introduced in API level 1 but `getAlpha()` was introduced in API level 19(KitKat). Is there any alternative API or support library to get the alpha/opacity value of the drawable.

And also I have NineOldAndroids library, but the `getAlpha()` works for only VIEWS.

Answer (score 6):

There is no general way of getting the alpha value of a Drawable prior of API 19.
Anyway, according to what kind of Drawable you have, you can check the source code to deduct the alpha with a workaround.

For instance looking at the [ColorDrawable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.java) source it's easy to see that you can port the implemention prior to Kitkat.

```
@Override
public int getAlpha() {
    return mColorState.mUseColor >>> 24;
}
```

so `drawable.getAlpha()` becomes `drawble.getColor() >>> 24`

**EDIT:**

here is a **uncomplete** attempt to make a compat method, i'll try to update this with time:

```
    public static int getAlphaCompat( Drawable drawable ) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return drawable.getAlpha();

    if( drawable instanceof ColorDrawable ) {
        return ((ColorDrawable) drawable).getColor() >>> 24;
    } else if( drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable ) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getPaint().getAlpha();
    } else if( drawable instanceof RotateDrawable ) {
        return getAlphaCompat( ((RotateDrawable) drawable).getDrawable() );
    } else if( drawable instanceof ScaleDrawable ) {
        return getAlphaCompat( ((ScaleDrawable) drawable).getDrawable() );
    } else if( drawable instanceof ClipDrawable ) {
        //TODO: possible with reflection
    } else if( drawable instanceof  ShapeDrawable ) {
        //TODO: possible with reflection
    } else if( drawable instanceof DrawableContainer ) {
       //TODO: possible with reflection
    } else if( drawable instanceof GradientDrawable ) {
        //TODO: possible with reflection
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I suggest insert `if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return drawable.getAlpha();` at the first.

Comment: And `return innerDrawable == null ? 255 : getAlphaCompat(innerDrawable)` for `RotateDrawable` and `ScaleDrawable` where `innerDrawable` is `drawable.getDrawable()`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this library to the build.gradle dependencies section:

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0
```

The next method becomes available on API level 4 and up:

```
DrawableCompat.getAlpha(Drawable d)
```

[Edit] **Attention** `DrawableCompat.getAlpha` just returns `0` for versions below 19. [See source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/compat/src/main/java/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.java#179)

Comment: The implementation for this for pre-19/KitKat SDKs is simply `return 0;` - beware this won't return the actual alpha value before KitKat.

Answer (score -2):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            v.setAlpha((Math.round(alpha*255)));
        }else{
            v.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
```

Comment: I have asked for GETTING the alpha value, but not setting it.

Comment: `setAlpha` is available from API 1.